# ¿Qué es y para que sirve OAuth?

Tags: oauth

Tengo una aplicación en spring mvc y he leído un poco de oauth para autenticar a mis usuarios pero la verdad no me ha quedado muy claro, ¿me podrían explicar de que se trata oauth?

Comment: -1 por "Esta pregunta no parece tener un trabajo de investigación".  ¿Leíste [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OAuth (Open Authorization) es un protocolo que permite flujos simples de autorización para sitios web o aplicaciones informáticas. Permite autorización segura de una API de modo estándar y simple para aplicaciones de escritorio, móviles y web.

Por ejemplo, si quieres hacer una autenticación de usuarios a tu página web vía Facebook (registro y login) puedes hacerlo con OAuth, de tal forma que este protocolo te permita el registro y login de usuarios con sus credenciales de Facebook.

Existen proyectos que te ayudan a integrar este tipo de protocolos en tus apps con MVC, como [este](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth) para spring

Espero que te ayude :)